# Query on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have no experience in mongodb. There are to objects e.g. books, I could store them as

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52ed37cb395d461424d81d51"),
  "book" : {
    "@id" : "1",
    "@date" : "2012-02-01",
    "title" : "XML Developer's Guide",
    "price" : "44.95",
    "description" : "An in-depth look at creating applications with XML."
  }
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52ed37cb395d461424d81d52"),
  "book" : {
    "@id" : "2",
    "@date" : "2013-10-16",
    "author" : "Mark Colsberg",
    "title" : "Dolor sit amet",
    "price" : "5.95",
    "description" : "Lorem ipsum"
  }
}
```

or in one file as

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52ed1df5395d46189868ae96"),
  "catalog" : {
    "book" : [{
        "@id" : "1",
        "@date" : "2012-02-01",
        "title" : "XML Developer's Guide",
        "price" : "44.95",
        "description" : "An in-depth look at creating applications with XML."
      }, {
        "@id" : "2",
        "@date" : "2013-10-16",
        "author" : "Mark Colsberg",
        "title" : "Dolor sit amet",
        "price" : "5.95",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum"
      }]
  }
}
```

Which option is the better way to store the information for creating facet search on it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to store each book as different document in documents' collection of books - use the first method.

What do you mean by "facet search"?
If you want text search, mongodb has this - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: With facet search, I think on advanced search functionality similar to sql queries. So if I store the information in mongodb or a rational db I want to query on them. I am not familiar with the query language for mongodb, but I can imagine there is no difference to search through a catalog array or a collection of books.

Comment: There are some differences between querying a relational system and MongoDB. In systems like CouchDB or MongoDB you can use for example Map/Reduce or in case of MongoDB the aggregation framework for querying.

Comment: i think Horizon_Net answer is too general. For topic starter - if you use my approach - each book is a separate document in documents collection, you can issue searches by book title, description, author, etc..

Comment: That make sense for me. If I like to query exact matches on [subdocuments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) e.g. ` db.test.find( {book: { author : "Mark Colsberg" } } )` I get no results. Is there a way to do it recursive, so that I could find all objects with a specific value of some fields, under assumption I would not know in which sub-level the field is defined?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your applications access your data. If you normally have read access on your data I would go with the second option. If you frequently update your data the first option could be the better choice.

Remember that NoSQL is different than relational systems. NoSQL works best when you design your data in the way which is best for your application.

Answer (score 0):

For a facet search you will want to use an actual FTS tech currently like Solr/Elastic Search/Sphinx/whatever.

MongoDB is currently not designed for faceted searching.

Comment: Thx for referencing this tools. I already [heard](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/59757486344/faceted-search-with-mongodb) about them.